# How to add up old filter to existing filter php

Tags: php, sql, database

I use some filters to display items. But my problem is that when I click a new filter after I clicked an old one, the old one will be removed.

```
        <form id="filters" method="post">
           <select name="genre" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                <option value="">Genre</option>
                <?php
                $query = 'SELECT * FROM `imslp_genre` WHERE 1';
                $result = $conn->query($query);
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        $thisGenre = $row['genre'];
                        echo "<option value='$thisGenre'>$thisGenre</option>";
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            <select name="instrument" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                <option value="">Instrument</option>
                <?php
                $query = 'SELECT * FROM `imslp_instruments` WHERE 1';
                $result = $conn->query($query);
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        $thisInstrument = $row['instruments'];
                        echo "<option value='$thisInstrument'>$thisInstrument</option>";
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </form>
```

```
        $query =
            'SELECT `sheets_title`,`sheets_genre_ID`, `sheets_instrument1`,`sheets_instrument2`, `sheets_difficulty`, `sheets_img`, `sheets_xml`, `sheets_id`, `difficulty`, `genre`, `arrangement`, `composers`, `instruments`, `instruments2`, `instruments3`, `instruments4`, `instruments5` FROM `imslp_sheets`,`imslp_genre`, `imslp_difficulty`, `imslp_arrangements`, `imslp_composers`, `imslp_instruments`, `imslp_instruments2`, `imslp_instruments3`, `imslp_instruments4`, `imslp_instruments5` WHERE `sheets_genre_ID`=`genre_ID` AND `sheets_difficulty`=`difficulty_ID` AND `sheets_arrangement_ID`=`arrangement_ID` AND`sheets_composer_ID`=`composers_ID` AND `sheets_instrument1`=`instruments_ID` AND `sheets_instrument2`=`instruments2_ID` AND `sheets_instrument3`=`instruments3_ID`AND `sheets_instrument4`=`instruments4_ID`AND `sheets_instrument5`=`instruments5_ID`';
        $genre = filter_input(
            INPUT_POST,
            'genre',
            FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS
        );
        $instrument = filter_input(
            INPUT_POST,
            'instrument',
            FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS
        );
```

Down here it checks if the filter isn't empty so I guess there should be changed something over here but I can't fight the right solution to remember the previous used filter.

```
     if (!empty($genre)) {
            $query .= " AND `genre` = '$genre'";
        }

        if (!empty($instrument)) {
            $query .= " AND `instruments` = '$instrument'";
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Basicly you have to do something like this:

```
echo "<option value='$thisGenre' "
     .($thisGenre==$genre?'selected':'')
     .">$thisGenre</option>";
```

This will select the option again, when the page is reloaded after submit.

See: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp